# Add Button to Graphics Canvas

Tags: android, android-view, android-fragmentactivity, android-graphics

I was using the answer to this question: [Drawing on Canvas and save image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401432/drawing-on-canvas-and-save-image) in order to create a canvas to draw an image on.

I am currently opening a `FragmentActivity` called `DrawImage` when a button is clicked. In this activity I want `MyDrawView` to be displayed along with a floating action button which will allow the user to save their drawing when clicked.

This is how I am currently displaying the canvas, which works, but I do not know how to add the button on top of it. Any ideas?

**DrawImage**

```
public class DrawImage extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View drawImageCanvas = new MyDrawView(this.getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(drawImageCanvas);
    }
}
```

**MyDrawView** (Same as on the link)

```
public class MyDrawView extends View {

private Bitmap  mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;
private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
private Paint   mPaint;

public MyDrawView(Context c) {
    super(c);

    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY =  y;
    }
}
private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void clear(){
    mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    invalidate();
    System.gc();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting contentView as **MyDrawView** view only, so there will not be any more views (Buttons) in the layout. It is impossible to add Buttons in such way.

Solution is to move **MyDrawView** to xml file (fragment_draw_image.xml) and set content v

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.misah.test.MyDrawView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save Drawing"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_draw_image);`  In the layout you have your drawing view and button on top of it, and anything else you wish.

**Edited:**

Add this constructors also to the **MyDrawView**, and you can use it from xml:

```
public MyDrawView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    init();
}

public MyDrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyDrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

public MyDrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
}
```

And add all that you are doint in Constructor to init method (drawing etc)

[image]

Comment: I have just tried this and got the following error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abby.mobiledevices/com.example.abby.mobiledevices.DrawImage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.abby.mobiledevices.MyDrawView`

Comment: It also says `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.abby.mobiledevices.MyDrawView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.abby.mobiledevices.MyDrawView
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]`

Answer (score 0):

The JVM can´t find your custom class MyDrawView. You must put the package name dot MyDrawView in the XML file (fragment_draw_image.xml)